# Get all the coincidences with given value from object array

Tags: javascript

I have this array of objects:

```
var hola = [{key:id , desc:description }];
// they are filled with data with ajax from a table
```

this are the values right now

```
    var hola = [
             {key: "AL-32021611", descc: "7500"}, 
             {key: "AL-32021612", descc: "Continental"}, 
             {key: "AL-32021612", descc: "R3"}, 
             {key: "AL-32021612", descc: "7500"}
             ];
```

what i need is that with a given value i get for example

```
   newarr= {key:AL-32021612}[descc:"continental", "r3", "7500"]
```

but from this 'newarr' i just need the key like some kind of index to get all its descc values in a var and im really lost and here is why

```
$.each(newarr, function (i, data) 
{ trHTML = '<div class="three_col_to_one_col categories">' + idVal[i] +'</div>' })
```

i will use this newarr as the length of this each and print its content but i just need this descc values for that, its complicated and messy but im new and i might get downvotes but thanks for reading me anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an empty object to use as a dictionary, where keys are ID's/keys and values are arrays of the "descc"s. Fill it out like this:

```js
var hola = [
    {key: "AL-32021611", descc: "7500"}, 
    {key: "AL-32021612", descc: "Continental"}, 
    {key: "AL-32021612", descc: "R3"}, 
    {key: "AL-32021612", descc: "7500"}
];

var dict = {};
hola.forEach(obj => {
    if (!dict[obj.key]) dict[obj.key] = [];
    dict[obj.key].push(obj.descc);
});

console.log(dict);
```

Then each array of `descc` could be accessed by ID: `dict["AL-32021612"]` would be the array `["Continental", "R3", "7500"]`

Comment: ES6, the answer is what i need but any sugestions for equivalences in that arrow of ES6 in older version?

Comment: ... you need an ES5 solution? Just use a normal function instead of an arrow function